# Extract letters from a string using the position

Tags: python, string, extract

I am a beginner with Python and I am using Python 2.7.

I have a DNA sequence (the string `dna`) and I have to extract letters according to their position in the dna string. The position is defined by the string `sequence`, in which the first number before the dots refers to the first letter to be extracted from the `dna` string and the second number to the last one.

I have to do this with a loop, keeping the python program as simple as possible. I have spent several days trying to write the code and I have been unable to make it work. Here is what I have done so far, but it doesn’t work. Any help?

```
dna='abcde'    
sequence=' 0..2, 4..5, 4..5'   
import re    
b=re.finditer('([0-9]{1}\.\.([0-9]{1}))', sequence)    
for j in b:        
   print int(j.group(2))    
a=re.finditer('(([0-9]{1})\.\.[0-9]{1})', sequence)    
for f in a:    
   print int(f.group(2))    
for element in sequence:    
   print dna[int(f.group(2)):int(j.group(2))]
```

Comment: Please show an example of what the expected output should look like, given the input you've shown above.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta. The expected output should like:
    ab
    e
    e
ab refers to the location 0..2 and e to 4..5.

Comment: The expected output should be "ab e e ab"?  What?  I assume you're missing some punctuation there.  Please take the time to use proper grammar, punctuation, etc. so it's as easy and non-confusing as possible for the people trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about...:

```
dna='abcde'    
sequence=' 0..2, 4..5, 4..5'   
import re    
b=re.finditer(r'([0-9]+)\.\.([0-9]+)', sequence)    
for j in b:        
   print dna[int(j.group(1)) : int(j.group(2))]
```

This prints

```
ab
e
e
```

since the slice, in Python, excludes the last index.  If you instead want to see `abc` and `ef`, just change the `print` to

```
   print dna[int(j.group(1)) : int(j.group(2)) + 1]
```

i.e, just add 1 to the right-hand part of the slice syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you omit `r` before your pattern :

```
>>> b=re.finditer(r'([0-9]{1}\.\.([0-9]{1}))', sequence) 
>>> for j in b:
...    print int(j.group(2))
... 
5
5
```

But for split the sequence you dont need regex you can use a list comprehension and `str.split()` :

```
>>> l=[i.split('..') for i in sequence.split(',')]
>>> [(int(i),int(j)) for i,j in l]
[(0, 2), (4, 5), (4, 5)]

>>> for i,j in indices :
...    print dna[i:j]
... 
ab
e
e
```

Comment: `print int(j.group(1))` this is not working. Did you check it?

Comment: @AerofoilKite it was a typo , fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
dna='abcde'    
sequence='0..2, 4..5, 4..5'
positionlist = sequence.split(", ") #splits string on, and puts parts in list
dnalist = list(dna) #splits to seperate letters
for i in xrange(len(positionlist)): #make an array of arrays (last array has 2 values, start and stop)
    range1 = positionlist[i].split("..") 
    range1 = map(int,range1) #convert from string to integer
    print dnalist[range1[0]:range1[1]]
```

This is an implementation without regex. May not be the easiest but I'm also a beginner just as you and did this as a test for myself.